# How to access the properties of this json object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Lets say I've a JSON object like this stored in a file maj.json, which I import into my main.js file like this

maj.json

```
{
  "prop1": {
    "p1": 12,
    "p2": "qwer"
  },
  "prop2": {
    "p1": 34,
    "p2": "asdf"
  },
  "prop3": {
    "p1": 56,
    "p2": "zxcv"
  }
}
```

In main.js

```
var js = require("./maj.json");
```

Now I've an array like this

```
var prop = ["prop2", "prop3"];
```

How can I get the properties listed in say, array prop from js. I tried like this, but it's not working. I'm getting **undefined** result with this approach.

```
for(str in prop) {
    console.log(js.prop[str]);
}
```

output for this :

```
undefined
undefined
```

How can I do something like this in the right way?

**EDIT**
More importantly how can i do this for inner properties like access prop2.p2 etc. dynamically, i.e both prop2 and p2 are given dynamically?

Comment: Use bracket notation: `js.str` ==> `js[str]`

Comment: still the same result

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over array. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/s68mu9j9/)